# Identifying subviews

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am looking for a way to identify a subview object while iterating inside a for-loop, I basically get all subviews from a UITableView's contentView by doing cell.contentView.subviews.

```
for SubView in cell.contentView.subviews {
   // check if it's the correct subview
}
```

basically thats how I get the subview objects into a loop, while I can see that I got multiple objects in there I need to somehow identify these, in C# a key named simply as name is defined as such:

```
object.name = "something"
```

and then retreived in a for-loop by:

```
object.name
```

but this doesn't seem to be a possibility in Swift, how would I go about identifying an object if I got multiple occurrences of let's say a UILabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `tag` property on UIView, although it's an integer and not a string. But you could use an enum to make it readable.

Comment: lassej is correct, `tag` is used most often to identify subviews, but if you are set on a more descriptive string identifier, create a new `UIView` subclass with whatever property you want to use -- `viewName` for example.